# Which type of portable heaters are best suited to use in a static caravan?

Tags: heating

I am looking for 2 portable heaters to use in a static caravan. One to go in the children's bedroom (safe to leave on at night), the other to go in the living room.

Which types of heaters would be most suitable for these situations?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living and thank you for your question. Please note that this website has a few rules for asking questions. For example, we don't allow 'shopping recommendation' questions because answers to such questions are very subjective and tend to be outdated soon. Also, all questions should have a link with sustainability. In your question this is not clear. For more information about asking questions please see our [Help Center](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @THelper I've reworded the question so that it should be on topic now. Let's reopen it.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I've reopened the question. I think we can assume the OP is also interested in efficiency and/or small environmental impact of the heaters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which type of portable electric heater is better?](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1306/99)